# Check if buffer was used in last query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb, micro-optimization

I was wondering whether there is any `query`/`config`/`trick`/etc to know if the `innodb_buffer` was used in the fetching of result for `last query`.

PS: This is in context of performance tuning, and I don't want to keep things to best guesses, so is there any way to provide a concrete evidence if `buffer_pool` was used or a normal db lookup was used.

PPS: I already searched for related terms like

- check if buffer was used mysql
- Innodb buffer used check
- Verify if results loaded from buffer pool or datastore.  etc..

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171/for-a-mysql-query-how-do-you-determine-physical-and-logical-i-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch for changes to `GLOBAL STATUS` values of `Innodb%`.  Ditto for `Handler%`.

I like to do this for figuring out what is going on in a query:

```
 FLUSH STATUS;
 SELECT ...
 SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

It tells me exactly how many rows are touched how many times.  And whether a temp table is being used and how big it is (in rows).  Etc.

The only way the buffer_pool won't be "used" in an InnoDB query is if the Query cache is used instead.

Probably what you are fishing for is not whether the buffer_pool is "used", but whether a block had to be fetched from disk before it could be used?